# Need a loop to add 30 minutes as a time in HTML

Tags: php, html

i have made a webpage using html and php that allows users to book appointments, but my slots are every 30 minutes but the way i am currently doing it will not add 30 minutes on to the database

```
<?php ob_start( ); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Nav.css">

    <title>Book Barber</title></head>
    <body>
    <?php
            echo " <div class='navigation'><a href='BarberHomeScreen.php'>Home</a><div class='dropdown'><button class='dropdownButton'>Account<i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></button><div class='dropdownContent'><a href='MyAccount.php'>My Account</a><a href='SignOut.php'>Sign Out</a></div></div></div>";
    ?>
        <h1>Booking a barber appointment for <?php session_start();echo $_SESSION['customerName'];?></h1>
        <form method="POST" action="#">

            <input type="date" name="selectDate" />
            <input type="submit" name="submitDate"/>  


        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submitDate'])){

                //if the submit button has been pressed, connect to the db
                //and search for all the available tables on that selected day
                $conn = mysql_connect(localhost, "root", "");
                if(!$conn){
                    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                }

                  $selectedDb = mysql_select_db('booking', $conn);
                  if(!$selectedDb){
                    die("Can't use the selected db: " . mysql_error());
                  }

                  //selects all the bookings for the date chosen in the form
                  $query= "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE BookingDate = '" . $_POST['selectDate'] . "' ORDER BY customerID, BookingTime";
                  $result = mysql_query($query);
                  //stop php while table headers outputted
                  ?>

                  <table border="1">
                      <tr></tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Barber</th>
                          <th>9:00</th>
                          <th>9:30</th>
                          <th>10:00</th>
                          <th>10:30</th>
                          <th>11:00</th>
                          <th>11:30</th>
                          <th>12:00</th>
                          <th>12:30</th>
                          <th>13:00</th>
                          <th>13:30</th>
                          <th>14:00</th>
                          <th>14:30</th>
                          <th>15:00</th>
                          <th>15:30</th>
                          <th>16:00</th>
                      </tr>
                  <?php //start php again to output the bookings available or not

                 /*The next bulk of php is outputting the table showing which slots are booked and which are available.
                 two while loops are needed, the outer one loops through the tables, the inner while loops through
                 each of the times for the table. 
                 Then while the loops are repeating they check if this booking
                 is for the current timeslot and table being looked at. If so it puts an X in the td and carries out mysql_fetch_assoc
                 again to get the next booking from the $result. This continues for each of the slots in the table. 
                 */
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                       $time = 9;
                       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
                       while($time <= 16){//time begins at 9 and stops at 16. Would be better to get this from the db too.
                           if((Time($row['BookingTime'])==$time)){
                               echo "<td style='background-color:lightCoral'>X</td>";
                               $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                           }else{
                               echo "<td style='background-color:lightGreen'><a href='MakeBarberBooking.php?&time=" . $time. "&date=" . $_POST['selectDate'] ."'>Book</a></td>";
                           }

                           $time=$time+0.5;
                       }
                        echo "</tr>";

                    }//end while


            //end if submit pressed

                ?>
                </table>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 

ob_end_flush( );
 ?>
```

the system loops through each time slot using the time=time+0.5 but that records the time as 10.5 instead of 10:30 for instance

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Refrain from using MySQL_* and use either MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: *"it will not add 30 minutes on to the database"* - What do you mean by that? Are you trying to INSERT or UPDATE?

Comment: INSERT, i am trying to get it to insert the time as  9:30 as a time, but it will add it as a completely different time like 12:04

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) function.

First create the start and end times. Then create a date interval and loop over the object.

N.B. its worth noting you may need to add the interval to the dtEnds to get the loop to include the last period.

```
// set format the date string is formatted as 
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

// set the start and end date 
$dtStarts = new DateTime();
$dtEnds   = new DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2017-12-01 06:00:00');

// create intervals that we would like to loop over
// i.e. 1 day at a time, or every 45 minutes
$dtInterval         = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 days');
$dtIntraDayInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('45 minutes');

// set day period/range
$dpPeriod = new DatePeriod( $dtCalStarts, $dtInterval, $dtCalEnds );

// loop oveer each period in the day
foreach ( $dpPeriod as $dtDay ){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($dtDay);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that ProEvilz already commented about Sql Injection, adding .5 will not magically make it into a date/time format.

Work with the date object (or DateTime class in php5.4+) and for each iteration you use this:

Initial value would be

```
$currentTime = "09:00";
$nextTime = date("H:i", strtotime($currentTime ." +30 MINUTE"));
```

$nextTime would be 09:30..